# persistent connections and wait timeout

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-pconnect

### Who maintains persistent connections pool?

I've looked a bit [at the source code](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c#818) and I understood that `mysql_pconnect` is a PHP made function and PHP itself is maintaining a pool of connections. It's not mysql's built in functionality and PHP only is responsible for maintaining a pool.  Which seems legit.
**Am I right ?**

### Slow queries killer?

I'm experiencing some problems with timed out connections.
My `my.cnf` has a configuration of `wait_timeout=5`. This is theoretically meant to kill queries that take more then 5 seconds to execute.

With this configuration I feel like I'm not achieving neither the 5 seconds limit per query, nor any benefits from persistent connections.

*Could you validate my thoughts and suggest something?*
*php 5.3.3, mysql 5.1 via mysql ext, no mysqlnd*

Comment: I'm still learning my way around StackOverflow so you may want to post your clarifications with the original, but clearly my answer is not relevant!  Happy Christmas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) should only kill idle connections.

To kill long running queries, you'll have to look into an external script.

The percona toolkit does have a tool that fits with what you want to do: [pt-kill](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-kill.html)